# getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById() doesn't return null even if it should

Tags: android, fragmentmanager

Im building dynamic UI for tablets with two fragments side by side.

I recognize which layout is displayed with `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.my_fragment)`, where my_fragments is 2nd fragment which is shown next to primary listfragment. But after some rotations and clicks getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById() returns fragment even if it shouldn't (another layout is displayed, only listfragment).

```
@Override
public void onRSSMessageSelected(int position) {
    AppEngine.getInstance().setRSSMessagePosition(position);
    // The user selected the RSSMessge from the RSSMessagesList

    // Capture the detail fragment from the activity layout
    RSSMessageDetail fragment = (RSSMessageDetail)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.rssmessage_detail);


    // BUG: supportManager doesn't return null even if it should
    if (fragment!=null) {
        fragment.updateRSSMessageDetail();

    } else {
        fragment = new RSSMessageDetail();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        //add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

layout-land:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment android:name="cz.cvut.sabattom.fragment.RSSMessagesList"
              android:id="@+id/feed_messages_list"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment android:name="cz.cvut.sabattom.fragment.RSSMessageDetail"
              android:id="@+id/rssmessage_detail"
              android:layout_weight="2"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do not define the fragments in XML, use a FrameLayout and create a `FragmentTransaction` to add/remove them. This way the FragmentManager will have a track of your Fragments and they will be part of the Layout.

Comment: This is Google sample code

Comment: Google Sample code doesn't necessarily apply for every user case.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with method isInLayout()

```
if (fragment!=null&&fragment.isInLayout()) {
    fragment.updateRSSMessageDetail();
}
```